# How to triggered AWSS3v3 server with akeneo-pim?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, akeneo

I have configured the ASWS3v3 as per the documentation provided at [How to connect to an external server for storage?](http://docs.akeneo.com/latest/cookbook/product_asset/how_to_connect_to_an_external_server.html#quick-overview). How can I triggered the assets to AWS bucket?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer.

Assets will be exported to AWS S3 bucket after you successfully able to upload any assets from your akeneo dashboard interface (i.e Dashboard > Enrich > Assets page) after configure the AWS export as per the cookbook.

Comment: Hey @Shrikant Glad you find yourself the solution. If you think the documentation should be improved, don't hesitate to contribute in https://github.com/akeneo/pim-docs ;)

Comment: Hey @Pierallard! Yes, I do think that documentation should improve and would like to contribute.